401 Unauthorized: Consuming web api with JWT authentication in .NET 8 MAUI
I have a webapi .net core 8.0 using JWT authorize, when i try to make a log-in using postman or swagger i can get a JWT token and use then to make a request to a protected end-point, all work perfectly. When i try to do the same thing on my client application Blazor.NET MAUI i receive a 401 code unauthorized. I can make log-in in client application and get the JWT token, but when i try to make a simple httpget to a protected end-point i get 401, the JWT token is the same in webapi and client app, i use this same JWT token in postman and work, i put the same token in http header of the request in client app and dosen't work :/, i verify the token in jwt.io.
Maybe the problem is in my client get method, i don't know.
protected async Task OnGet()
{
    string? userDetailsStr = await SecureStorage.GetAsync(nameof(UserBasicDetail));

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userDetailsStr))
    {
        var userBasicDetail = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserBasicDetail>(userDetailsStr);
        string? token = userBasicDetail!.AccessToken;

        // Create the HTTP client using the API named factory
        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory?.CreateClient("API");

        //httpClient!.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

        // Execute the GET operation and store the response, the empty parameter
        // in GetAsync doesn't modify the base address set in the client factory 
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("api/Paciente");


        // If the operation is successful deserialize the results into the data model
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            Pacientes = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Paciente>>(contentStream);
        }
    }
}

the http header response:

{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
Date: Wed, 17 Apr 2024 15:13:46 GMT
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
Content-Length: 0
}}

Some logs:

2024-04-17 11:42:46.5686|9|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler|AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was not authenticated.
2024-04-17 11:42:46.5686|0|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware|Policy authentication schemes  did not succeed
2024-04-17 11:42:46.5686|2|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService|Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of the following roles: (User|Admin)

I have a custom GetAuthenticationStateAsync method i don't know if this has something to do with it or not
public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // Verifica se há informações de usuário armazenadas
        var userInfo = await SecureStorage.GetAsync(nameof(UserBasicDetail));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInfo))
        {
            // Se não houver informações de usuário, retorna um estado de autenticação nulo
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }

        // Desserializa as informações do usuário
        var userBasicDetail = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserBasicDetail>(userInfo);

        // Cria claims para o usuário com base nas informações obtidas
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new(ClaimTypes.Name, userBasicDetail!.Email!),
            new(ClaimTypes.Role, userBasicDetail.Role!)
            // Adicione outras claims conforme necessário
        };

        // Cria um objeto ClaimsIdentity com as claims do usuário
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Bearer");

        // Retorna o estado de autenticação com o usuário autenticado
        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Em caso de erro, lança uma exceção ou trata conforme necessário
        throw new ApplicationException("Erro ao obter o estado de autenticação", ex);
    }
}

I am completely stuck in this.

Postman has a control panel which will contains all the HTTP headers.  Postman is more robust than c# code and will automatically adds HTTP headers when necessary.  The solution is to get the actual HTTP request from the postman control panel and then add the missing headers to your c# code.

I tried this, I didn't succeed, thanks for the suggestion.

What did you find with Postman Control Panel?

https://imgur.com/a/9DDps3G the Authorization Bearer is there.
I tried use wireshark to capture a http packet from my application, the bearer token appear there to https://imgur.com/t19Unqi

Looks like both links are the same wireshark message for postman.  Can you post the wireshark for c#?  Both links the Frame is 478.  Postman sometime will try more than once using different parameters.  Make sure the Postman response frame contains 200 OK.

i apologize for misunderstood, this link https://imgur.com/Q0OGqcK is from postman and this https://imgur.com/cp8jXEP is from c# client app, in the header of c# client i doesn't include the cookie because my default atuheticate scheme is set to JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, even when i delete this cookie from the http request in postman it work fine.

Is there any differences with postman with and without the cookie?

don't have difference, the request is successful in postman with out cookie

c# has same http headers as postman without cookie?  May be you are going through a proxy with c#.

has the same header, this is very strange, don't have any proxy in application

If the HTTP message is exactly the same both c# and postman will always work  So either there is a difference or there is a timeout that is not the same.
